# Can being a Google 'Trusted Store' increase organic search engine rank? Or, not being one decrease rank?

Tags: seo, ecommerce

For an e-commerce website, I'm wondering if being a Google Trusted Store or not affects search engine ranking. [From this article](http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/news/2253941/matt-cutts-merchant-quality-to-affect-google-search-rankings)

Comment: I would thing so. It would make sense.